# Lettrine and Arabic script

Tags: lettrine, persian

I am trying to typeset texts with numbered, non-titled chapters with latex and want the chapter number always large in the text. I have used lettrine in latin script text successfully, but I get horrible text overlaps in Arabic script. This is what I do.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \title{(My title)}
    \date{}

    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{farsi}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Gentium}
    \newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Nazli}


    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{farsi}


    \lettrine[lines=3]{1}{ }    تقدیم به عالیجناب تئوفیلوس:

تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام         کردهاند
     \end{farsi}
     \end{document}
```

Any useful suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post a Minimal Working Example? You are more likely to get useful answers if people can reproduce the problem you're having easily. Basically, show us just enough code for us to be able to compile your example and see the problem you're having. Then people will try to adapt it and post back modified versions which may resolve the problem.

Comment: @cfr 

        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{polyglossia}
        \usepackage{lettrine}
        \title{(My title)}
        \date{}

        \setmainlanguage{english}
        \setotherlanguage{farsi}
        \newfontfamily\englishfont{Gentium}
        \newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Nazli}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{farsi}
\lettrine[lines=3]{1}{ }    تقدیم به عالیجناب تئوفیلوس:

تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام کردهاند
\end{farsi}
\end{document}`

Comment: I can't reproduce as I don't have that font but hopefully somebody else does.

Comment: The font can bew replaced with another - Scheerazadeh does the same. http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Scheherazade

Comment: In principle, the `bidi` package is aware of `lettrine`, since it patches it, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. And please do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than “user1234”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realised that switching the chapter number demonstrated the problem. (With a '1' it is much less obvious there is overlap between text and number. An '8' makes this clear.)

The problem, I think is that lettrine is designed to cope with a *paragraph* but the original code included a paragraph break after the first line. So subsequent lines did not get indented correctly. Using a line break rather than a paragraph break avoids this problem. I've set the chapter number in \englishfont but it works with \farsifont also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\title{(My title)}
\date{}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Gentium}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Scheherazade-R.ttf}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\farsifont}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\englishfont}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{farsi}

\lettrine[lines=3]{8}{ }    تقدیم به عالیجناب تئوفیلوس:\\
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام         کردهاند

\end{farsi}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: No idea what it means but I take it it is Farsi with dropped Arabic numberal as chapter number (or would be if this was a chapter)]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, which is that with the Arabic font, the (Arabic) digit overlaps the text.

Comment: @AlanMunn I said it was not intended as an answer. Just the problem was not at all clear to me until I changed the chapter number which made the overlap obvious.

Comment: You're welcome. It was interesting working with a script so different, even if it was incomprehensible to me. So that was intriguing but then I kind of liked the fact that the problem turned out to have nothing to do with its being Arabic script at all!

Comment: @peter Unlike Hasan Zakeri, I don't know anything about typesetting Persian as such - I am just somewhat fascinated by fonts in general. (Which is why my answer *just* answered the question - I'm in no position to advise anybody on formatting Persian!)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if you are typesetting in Persian, you should *totally* consider using `xepersian` instead of `polyglossia`.

Second, using `lettrine` in non-latin scripts needs a special consideration: your font must have `x` character. Otherwise you will get a divide by zero error. You can see comments of Vafa Khalighi, author of `bidi` on this issue [here](http://www.parsilatex.com/forum/SMF/index.php?topic=1966.msg11966#msg11966) in persian.

This example here typesets what you meant with `xepersian`, and with no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xepersian}   
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=3]{1}{ }    تقدیم به عالیجناب تئوفیلوس:\\
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام             کردهاند
 تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام         کردهاند 
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام         کردهاند
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام         کردهاند
\end{document}
```

[image: lettrine with xepersian]

Take note please, that you need at least 3 lines of text after `\lettrine`. Hence I copied your text multiple times.

Now if you insist on using `polyglossia`, here's a working example of `\lettrine`. The only modification is removing paragraph break to avoid merging dropped letter with the next paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\title{(My title)}
\date{}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Gentium}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{B Nazanin}{Nazli}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{farsi}


\lettrine[lines=3]{1}{ }    تقدیم به عالیجناب تئوفیلوس:\\
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام         کردهاند
\end{farsi}
\end{document}
```

[image: lettrine with polyglossia]

You may also want to define a `chapter` counter, and a `\chapter` control sequence to automate this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xepersian}   
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\newcounter{chapter}
\newcommand{\chapter}{%
    \vskip2em
    \stepcounter{chapter}%
    \lettrine[lines=3]{\arabic{chapter}}{}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter
    تقدیم به عالیجناب تئوفیلوس:\\
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام    کردهاند 
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام کردهاند 
تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام             کردهاند تا به حال نویسندگان بسیاری به نوشتن شرح وقایعی كه در بین ما رخ داده است، اقدام کردهاند
\end{document}
```